# how to check whether a variable is a class or not in c#

Tags: c#, variables, types, new-operator

I have a function that gets a `object` as a parameter

ex:

```cs
public static void doSomthingWithObject(object obj)
{
 (.....)
}
```

and I want to check whether the object I got is a class or a simple variable (e.g if it requires a constructor to create) and if so, I want to get all the properties of that `object` so the code will look something like that:

```cs
public static void doSomthingWithObject(object obj)
{
 if(objectIsClass())
  {
    object[] arr = obj.getAllPropeties
 (.....)
  }
  else
  {
 (.....)
  }
}
```

is that possible?

edit:
people found my definition to class variables and simple variables confusing. to make it clear, "simple variable" is a variable that can hold only one value, and to access this value you need to simply write "= var" while  "class variable" can hold  multiple values (unless it has 1-0 properties), and each one of its values can be accessed using `get`  ex: `= obj.prop` (unless there is no `get`) each value in this type of variable is held by a property, and to define a new class property the `new` keyword must be used

Comment: Maybe this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What about `struct`?

Comment: @Johnny so it returns ```true``` if its ```int, string, etc...```?

Comment: @avivgood3 should be carefull about `struct` look at the answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok but how I do ```obj.getAllPropeties```?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I said, whether  "if it requires a constructor to create" or not

Comment: `(e.g if it requires a constructor to create)` **Every type** requires a constructor to create. `string` and some other types (`int` etc) _look_ like they don't, but they are still constructed under the covers. What are the **specific** types you are interested in, and why?

Comment: `a class or a simple variable` Please list 7 examples of what you are think are `class` and what are `simple variable`. _You are using the wrong terminology, so this is to try and work out exactly what you mean._

Comment: Imagine any class having an [implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators). You wouldn't need to write `SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();`, you could just write `SomeClass instance = otherThing;`. How would that factor in your idea of "requires a constructor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, everything that you see is either a class or a struct, (Int is struct for example).

So the question comes down to two things,

1. Do you want to know all the types which do not have a parameterless constructor (like int doesn't have)
   To do that,

   ```
   bool ObjectIsClass(object o)
   {
      return  o.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[0])!=null;
   }
   ```
2. Do you want to Look for Primitive types

   ```
   bool IsPrimitive(object o)
   {
      return o.GetType().IsPrimitive;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do it:

```
    public static void DoSomethingWithObject(Object obj)
    {
        if (!obj.GetType().IsPrimitive)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a class.");
            var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var p in properties) {
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is NOT a class.");
        }
    }
```

Not exactly sure what you mean by "get all properties". But this code will check if the indata is an instance of a non-primitive class and give you the name of all the properties. Perhaps it is a start.

Comment: "so it returns true if its int, string, etc..." - so while you think it "should do it" it actually does not.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood his question. But to me, this sorts out "simple variables", as he put it, from instances of classes.

Comment: Take special note that `string` is *not* primitive.